# Почему не срабатывает псевдокласс :hover и :active к элементам меню?

Tags: css

Есть [сайт](http://evolutionnailspanj.brandivo.com/), на котором есть Главное меню на синем фоне. Я не могу понять, почему не срабатывает псевдокласс :hover и :active к элементам меню. Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении мыши веcь квадрат li с пунктом меню подсвечивался цветом #8ad4f7. Какой CSS нужно описать для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае обращайтесь к `li:hover a`

Comment: @Дмитрий Клименко Написал, но ничего не происходит...

Comment: Заработало с !important

Comment: Тогда так, исходя из разметки, немного повысим специфичность li:hover >a

Answer (score 0):

у вас так

```
#top #header .av-main-nav > li > a { 
      background-color: #0167B5;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 18px;
    }

    ul#avia-menu li a:hover { 
     background-color: #8AD4F7;
     color: white;
     font-size: 18px;
     height: 80px;
     line-height: 80px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

1 вараинт

```
ul#avia-menu li a:hover { 
     background-color: #8AD4F7!important;
     color: white;
     font-size: 18px;
     height: 80px;
     line-height: 80px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

2 вариант

```
#top #header .av-main-nav > li > a:hover{
     background-color: #8AD4F7;
     color: white;
     font-size: 18px;
     height: 80px;
     line-height: 80px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
```